# Calling Python from c#

Tags: c#, python, .net, python.net

Is the Pythonnet project still supported?

Portal is not recognized in code below and I can't find much documentation.

```
     PythonEngine.Initialize();
        PyObject pyportal = PythonEngine.ImportModule("PyPortal");
        PyObject callable = pyportal.GetAttr("invoke");
        Portal portal = new Portal();
        object[] objects = portal.Invoke(callable, "Mark Barclay", 123.456);
        if (objects != null)
        {
            foreach (object o in objects)
            {
                if (o != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("o is null.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can't instantiate classes from Python like that

Comment: This is in c#. As detailed here http://pythondotnet.python.narkive.com/WK3v2R0p/python-net-example-of-calling-python-from-c-with-simple-object-marshalling

Comment: I see, I think it is explained further below how to import it

Comment: But seems like a very old project. I can't seem to find anything more modern though

Comment: Did you add the portal class to your project? Like @Andrey said further down on that link he states you need to create the Portal.cs class in your project your self.

Comment: I tried but things like RuPyTuple_New don't exist in RunTime

Comment: pythonnet is quite active and developed at github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet You can use the simplified dynamic interface described here: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/README.md There is also mailing list https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/pythondotnet

Comment: You need to show the errors and traceback that you are getting from calling this mysterious PyPortal

Answer (score 1):

I also found this example when starting to explore python for .NET. It actually refers to an old version of pythonnet, the new version has documentation here: [pythonnet](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html#installation).
I'll be honest I'm still having trouble getting my imports to work, but many others seem to have success with this. You can install with a pip install which I found very handy. This [troubleshooting page](https://github.com/denfromufa/pythonnet/wiki/Troubleshooting-FAQ#no-left-over) has also been helpful for me. Goodluck!